# Is there a slack integration or app which provides running HTML+CSS+JS code snippets?

Tags: web-apps, chat, communication

I have recently set my students with [hipchat](http://hipchat.com) just because I liked an integration on hipchat called [HTMLCanvas](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/html-canvas-add-on/cloud/overview). But unfortunately this integration does not allow including external JavaScript libraries (such as reactjs) and it does not work in hipchat desktop version at all.

So I decided to use [slack](http://slack.com) instead because compared to hipchat, it has a lot more to offer.

Is there any integration for slack that provides a playground like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [Codepen](https://codepen.io/)?